# FindMaximum ignores MaxIterations option

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to find a maximum of interpolated function inside a particular mesh cell. However, for some cells the process is very slow and it returns a warning:

> FindMinimum::eit: The algorithm does not converge to the tolerance of 1.`*^-6 in 500 iterations

The code is:

```
FF = Interpolation[q, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
dp = 
  DensityPlot[FF[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 2], 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 40];
ms = DelaunayMesh[kekL, MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Opacity[0]}];
pg = MeshPrimitives[ms, 2][[104]];
fm = 
  FindMaximum[{FF[x, y], {x, y} ∈ pg}, {{x, pg[[1, 1, 1]]}, {y, pg[[1, 1, 2]]}}, 
    MaxIterations -> 30]
Show[
  {dp, ms,
   Graphics[{White, Point[{x, y} /. fm[[2]]], Point[RegionCentroid[pg]]}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

The definitions of `q` and `kekL` are on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gJuuxQrV).

I don't want a particularly accurate solution (even 10^-2 precision is fine)m but I'd like it to be fast. I tried using option `MaxIterations` but no matter what the parameter was it still reported "500 iterations" warning. It seems like it's ignoring eveything I put like `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` as well. The version is 11.2

Comment: Is it at all possible that the error is coming from somewhere else in your code?  Your error says "FindMinimum" and yet your pasted code (on this page) is for "FindMaximum"...

Comment: @MattStein that is the error you get. Probably because "FindMaximum" is some kind of "FindMinimum" with inverse sign under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the use of a region is calling an optimizer and options are not being passed (*see below).  It should probably be reported to WRI as a potential bug to see what they say.

Here's a way to enforce the constraint, by constructing one's own penalty function.  We also use a second starting point so that `FindMaximum` will avoid using the derivative of `FF`, which is not smooth.

```
dist[x_, y_] = RegionDistance[pg, {x, y}];
penalty[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Unitize[#] + # &@dist[x, y];
fm = FindMaximum[
  FF[x, y] - 
   penalty[x, y], {{x, y}, RegionCentroid@pg, pg[[1, 1]]}\[Transpose],
   MaxIterations -> 30]
(*  {0.200105, {x -> 0.789665, y -> -1.60565}}  *)

Show[
 Plot3D[{FF[x, y], FF[x, y] - penalty[x, y]}, {x, y} ∈ pg],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{x, y, FF[x, y]} /. Last@fm, 0.01]}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

*Update: Another workaround*

The discussion in the addendum below suggests using `RegionMember` instead of `Element` as a workaround:

```
FindMaximum[{FF[x, y], 
  RegionMember[pg, {x, y}]}, {{x, pg[[1, 1, 1]]}, {y, pg[[1, 1, 2]]}},
  MaxIterations -> 2]
```

> FindMaximum::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 2 iterations.

(*  {0.195039, {x -> 0.742393, y -> -1.64621}}  *)

With the option settings as follows, we get a result without error/warning messages:

```
FindMaximum[{FF[x, y], RegionMember[pg, {x, y}]},
 {{x, pg[[1, 1, 1]]}, {y, pg[[1, 1, 2]]}},
 PrecisionGoal -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 2, MaxIterations -> 7]
(*  {0.200033, {x -> 0.788627, y -> -1.60954}}  *)
```

---

*Addendum.*

The following shows that `FindMinimum` is called with the default setting for the options.  For some reason, after `FindMinimum` fails multiple times, `FindMaximum` seems to be run.  I'm pretty sure it's an internal function being run as a proxy, but it's curious.  A `Trace[]` show it is running `FindMinimum` on `-FF[x,y]` for two of the three line segments making up the triangle `pg` and then on the polygon; it seems it skips one of the line since it didn't show up.  It would be nice to eliminate what seem to be extraneous `FindMinimum` runs, but they might be helping to narrow down a solution, I suppose.  Someone with time to `Trace[]` the computation might be able to shed more light.

```
With[{opts = Options@FindMinimum},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetOptions[FindMinimum, MaxIterations -> 1],
  ffm = FindMaximum[{FF[x, y], {x, y} ∈ pg}, {{x, 
      pg[[1, 1, 1]]}, {y, pg[[1, 1, 2]]}}, MaxIterations -> 30],
  SetOptions[FindMinimum, opts]
  ]
 ]
```

> FindMinimum::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 1 iterations.
>   ... [two more messages] ...
>   General::stop: Further output of FindMinimum::cvmit will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> FindMaximum::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 30 iterations.

```
(*  {0.200079, {x -> 0.794926, y -> -1.60892}} v *)
```

By reducing `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`, one can also reduce the number of iterations needed.  Note the option values have to be set in both places:

```
With[{opts = Options@FindMinimum},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetOptions[FindMinimum,
   {PrecisionGoal -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 2, MaxIterations -> 30}],
  ffm = FindMaximum[{FF[x, y], {x, y} ∈ pg}, {{x, 
      pg[[1, 1, 1]]}, {y, pg[[1, 1, 2]]}},
    PrecisionGoal -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 1, MaxIterations -> 30],
  SetOptions[FindMinimum, opts]
  ]
 ]
```

> FindMinimum::eit: The algorithm does not converge to the tolerance of 0.01` in 30 iterations. The best estimated solution, with feasibility residual, KKT residual, or complementary residual of {2.78834*10^-11,0.0152532,1.39416*10^-11}, is returned.

```
(*  {0.200107, {x -> 0.790959, y -> -1.60642}}  *)
```

Here is the tracing code:

```
With[{opts = Options@FindMinimum},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetOptions[FindMinimum, MaxIterations -> 1],
  Trace[
   FindMaximum[{FF[x, y], {x, y} ∈ pg}, {{x, 
      pg[[1, 1, 1]]}, {y, pg[[1, 1, 2]]}}, MaxIterations -> 30],
   _FindMinimum,
   TraceInternal -> True],
  SetOptions[FindMinimum, opts]
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

With method `Spline` in `Interpolation` works fine.

```
 FF = Interpolation[q, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline"]
 dp = DensityPlot[FF[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 2], PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 40];
 ms = DelaunayMesh[kekL, MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Opacity[0]}];
 pg = MeshPrimitives[ms, 2][[104]];
 fm = FindMaximum[{FF[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] pg}, {{x, pg[[1, 1, 1]]}, {y, pg[[1, 1, 2]]}}, MaxIterations -> 30]

 (* {0.203597, {x -> 0.786015, y -> -1.64726}} *)

 Show[{dp, ms, Graphics[{White, Point[{x, y} /. fm[[2]]], 
 Point[RegionCentroid[pg]]}]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: Explanation of the differences in our methods: The spline method constructs a moderately smooth interpolation that works well with derivative based methods.  In my answer, by giving a second point, a method is selected that avoids derivatives.  The difference in the result is due to the difference in the interpolating functions constructed by the interpolation methods and has nothing to do with the optimization methods.

Comment: Should the process be much faster if I plug in `MaxIterations->2`? I'm trying to find maximums for all cells with Table instead of 104 element (see line 4 of the code). Maybe it still ignores the number of iterations.

Comment: @VsevolodA. Use:`fm = FindMaximum[{FF[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] pg}, {{x, 
     pg[[1, 1, 1]]}, {y, pg[[1, 1, 2]]}}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming` and You can check it's faster or not.